# How to achieve thread synchronizing without effecting the efficiency in java

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronization, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

Say using following function:

```
getUnique(){
    MyObject obj = getValueFromDb();
    obj.modifyIt();
    obj.commit();
}
```

When simultaneous call is made to this method several threads share same value of the MyObject, but I expected each thread to have a unique value.

To fix this I used thread synchronizing using `class.getInstance().myMethodCall()` to get unique value of some property, this solved the purpose, but as simultaneous call comes it reduces the efficiency of function.

Is there some better way to fix this? (Using STRUTS, HIBERNATE3.0)

Comment: Knowing what's inside myMethodCall would help: how do you connect to the db? Are you sharing the connection?

Comment: @savinos There is nothing except a couple of changes in properties. Can Assume that Hibernate transaction is started as method starts and commits at end of method call.

Comment: yes getValueFromDb() is synchronized

Comment: Are you using a persistence API such as Hibernate to perform your data access?  If so, the duplicate values could be due to caching.

Comment: @mcfinnigan  Using HIBERNATE3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Hibernate, each thread has its own session, and each session has a different set of objects. Each thread will thus have its own copy of MyObject. The database will handle concurrent modifications for you. If you want to forbid two threads modifying the same object at the same moment, use optimistic concurrency, with a @Version field, as described in the Hibernate documentation.

Synchronization is not the right tool here, because if your app is clustered or if the object is modified by another app or even another method, the synchronization won't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that "several threads share same value of the MyObject" is wrong. MyObject is not an instance variable, therefore it won't be shared with other threads.

Comment: MyObject has a value received by getValueFromDb and when the thread is in process and before it tries to commit another thread comes and access method , then both thread shares same value.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say 2 things to you, first is as @Umesh pointed, each thread is having its own copy of MyObject, they are not sharing the copy

and secondly, the function getValueFromDb() is also external, Have you ensured that getValueFromDb() is also synchronized. if Not? then you should synchronize it too.

Also, what is inside myMethodCall()??? Does it return the same value which getValueFromDb() returns??

Comment: yes getValueFromDb() is synchronized and comments posted to Umesh